# onclick inside of template literals does not work inside of wrapper function

Tags: javascript

I have a script that i want to wrap to avoid conflicting scope however when I wrap it, the onclicks in the template literals do not work. Throws an error saying function not defined.

```js
(function () { 
    
    function fillElement() {
        
        var body = `
            <button onclick = "alertSomething()">Click Me</button>
        `;
        
        document.getElementById("fillMe").innerHTML = body;
        
    }
    
    fillElement();
    
    function alertSomething() {
        alert("Hello World");
    }
    
})();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<HTML>
    <HEAD>
    </HEAD>
    <BODY>
        
        <div id = "fillMe">
            
        </div>
        
    </BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: Sure. The alertSomething is hidden inside the wrapped function. The HTML element's attributes will point to the globally defined functions, not to the scoped ones. You have to  define alertSomething as window.alertSomething to be visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, you cannot do it like this.

The alertSomething is hidden inside the wrapped function. The HTML element's attributes will always point to the functions defined on the "window" object, not to the scoped ones. You have to assign `alertSomething` to `window.alertSomething` to be visible in the HTML attribute. But this will also make it visible globally. It is not good approach to define event listeners in HTML attributes like that.

You should instead create elements as javascript objects (instead of strings), and dynamically attach the event listeners using javascript's `addEventListener` method like:

```js
(function () {

  function alertSomething() {
    alert("Hello World");
  }

  function fillElement() {
    const buttonElement = document.createElement('button');
    buttonElement.innerText = 'Click Me';
    buttonElement.addEventListener('click', alertSomething);

    document.getElementById("fillMe").appendChild(buttonElement);
  }

  fillElement();
})();
```